# How to create a User Registration page using Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I went create Form(Name Address cityId stateId) using Xamarin Android I have no idea How to data pass Xml file to cs file

Answer (score 1):

Probably this [Quickstart](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/) guide from Xamarin developer website could help. In short, you could give IDs for the element in your `.axml` (Android XML) file, then use `FindViewById` to access it in your `.cs` (Activity) file.

**EDIT**

*Storing Data*

To save the data to database in Android, you could use SQLite. It is an opensource database which is built in in Android devices. Xamarin developer website also have [a recipe](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite/) to help you getting started. And of course, the data is stored locally in the device.

If you would like to store the data online, what you could do is create a web server with a database. Your application then could use HTTP `GET` or `POST` to do CRUD through web service layer. To create a web service layer, you could use server-side scripting language, such as `NodeJS`, `PHP`, or other scripting language.

Comment: I see the documents but how to data pass xml to cs file (Because i already API call And create new xml file and cs file its working but how to data store in database )

Comment: I have edited my answer and there is a link to help you getting started. Hope it could help.